# Let $f$ be continuous and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open, if $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ is injective then $n \leq m$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I had intended to restrict the image then $f:U \rightarrow f(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^m $ is bijective. Therefore $\dim f(U) = n \leq m$.

That's right?

Comment: $U=\{0\}$, $f(0)=0$. $f$ is injective, but $n$ and $m$ can be whatever you like.

Comment: Be careful: Space filling curves are *far* from injective. Invariance of domain rules that out. But what do you mean by dimension?  Is $U$ meant to be open?

Comment: You can't really meaningfully talk about “$\dim f(U)$” unless $f(U)$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^m$. Unless more restrictions are placed on $U$ and $f$, this may not be the case.

Comment: well, you can always talk about homeomorphic to a vector space for dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is "invariance of domain" from basic algebraic topology. It is not easy to prove in any elementary way for merely-continuous $f$. For $f$ at least once-differentiable, it is elementary, because then dimension of tangent spaces (a genuinely vector-space notion of "dimension") is sufficient.

Comment: Using the dimension of the tangent space? I can say that $U$ is a regular surface, since it is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the tangent space of $U$ at the point $x$ is the kernel of the derivative  applied in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I do not know how to continue.

Comment: The differential $df$ of $f$ maps the tangent space of $U$ (at a given point) to the tangent space of the target. This $df$ is a linear map of those vector spaces, and, if injective, is ... again... an injective linear map of vector spaces. This gives the inequality of dimensions.

Comment: Yes, but we do not know the injectivity of df.

Comment: It is becoming less clear to me what hypotheses you _do_ have, then. Was the situation meant to evoke counter-examples to simple-sounding versions of true theorems? Invariance of domain applies to (local) homeomorphisms. The "df" argument applies to $C^1$ maps when $df$ is reasonably behaved.

Comment: And $f$ is a class function $C^k, k \ge 1$.How does it get better?

Comment: The local condition that $f$ is $C^1$ does not exclude some pathologies, such as a path in $\mathbb R^2$ that behaves well except for curving around and coming back to run into itself... except omitting that last point. Thus, locally at that point, the image looks like a "T". But $f$ is smooth and has injective $df$ everywhere... but this does not exclude these tricky pathologies.