# A $C^1$ injection makes $m \leq n$.

Tags: analysis

Let $m,n \geq1$, $U$ is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is an injection, if $f$ is $C^1$-differentiable on $U$, then $m \leq n$.

If $f$ is just continuous and injective on $U$, then $m \leq n$, too?

I have found that there is the same question in the next link, but is seems that it has not been resolved out.

[Let $f$ be continuous and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open, if $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ is injective then $n \leq m$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853723/let-f-be-continuous-and-u-subset-mathbbrn-open-if-f-u-rightarrow-m?rq=1)

Comment: what is $m$ ???

Comment: Have you studied Homology Theory ? The answer to both the questions is yes by the way. The proof of the second assertion that I know depends on  the Excision Principle of Homology Theory.

Comment: Basically in the second case, $f$ becomes a homeomorphism. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain.